# Does variable declaration initializes function?

Tags: javascript

Alright, this is probably a very basic question but I am new to programming (javascript = 1st language) and I couldn't find the answer on stackoverflow, so please be kind.

Does variable declaration initializes function? 
For example:

```
<script>
var myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},1000);

function myTimer()
{
var d=new Date();
var t=d.toLocaleTimeString();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=t;
}
</script>
```

I thought we needed to do `myVar();` as well but apparently not as the time keeps updating on the page.

http://jsfiddle.net/PHu52/1/

Comment: setInterval is evaluated (called) as the parenthesis are present, and the result of the function is returned to the variable.

Comment: You answered your own question...

Comment: @adeneo That clarifies it. So if I had only declared a function instead of calling it with parenthesis, THEN I would have to specifically call the function with myVar();

Comment: Google "mdn setinterval" : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval.

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` takes two parameters: a function and an integer. It then sets an interval to execute *the function* every *<integer>* microseconds. `setInterval` ***returns*** an identifier for the interval it just set, so you can later cancel the running interval using `clearInterval`.

So, only this will set and run the interval:

```
setInterval(myFunc, 1000);
```

This is how you use the returned id to cancel the interval:

```
var interval = setInterval(myFunc, 1000);
clearInterval(interval);
```